# Inserting Special Characters in SQL insert query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

The sql statement I am trying to execute is

```
INSERT INTO Scanners (Character) VALUES ('~')
```

The characters I would like to insert are:
{,}, [, ^ , & , ~, ` , : , ;.

But it says syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? and what's your dbms?

Comment: MS Access. It is just saying syntax error.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: You should be able to insert the characters you listed without a problem.   Isn't `Character` a reserved word in Access though?  Maybe you just need to escape it with brackets.  If not, show your entire table structure.

Comment: I think key word should be the reason. Do you mind to tell me how to escape the characters with brackets?

Comment: @sgeddes, You are right man, character is a key word in access. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `[]`.

```
INSERT INTO [Scanners] ([Character]) VALUES ('~')
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the name of the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chr function to insert special characters. So for example, to insert '~', you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO Scanners (Character) VALUES ('' || Chr(126) || '') -- 126 is ascii for ~
```

Note, I'm not in front of my machine with environment set up to test this.